# How to add items to a list in similar check box format from user input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, checkbox

I am trying to make an editable check list, using check boxes. One feature I would like is for users to be able to add their own items to this list.

With the help of another user, I have got this far:
HTML:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <label for="checkbox65">
            <input name="checkbox65" class="checkbox65" type="checkbox" />
            Get directions for where you are going
        </label>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <label for="textinput4">
                    Add new item
                    <input name="new_item" id="textinput4" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                </label>
            </fieldset>
            <button id="add">Add</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#add').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $firstRow=$this.closest('table').find('tr:first');
    var $newRow = $firstRow.clone();
    $newRow.find(':input').prop('checked', false);
    $newRow.insertAfter($firstRow);
 });
```

What I'm trying to get is something that looks a bit like this:
[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HByMl.jpg)

But at the moment it just repeats the original check box with label.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need to set the text next to the checkbox to what you enter in the input box, you can do:

```
$('#add').on('click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $firstRow=$this.closest('table').find('tr:first');
    var $newRow = $firstRow.clone();

    var input = $newRow.find(':input').remove();
    input.prop('checked', false);
    $newRow.empty().append(input).append('&nbsp;'+$('#textinput4').val());

    $newRow.insertAfter($firstRow);
});​
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/VHe6C/

Comment: Eureka! That's it exactly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the text box value for the check box

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#addbutton").on("click",function(){
if ($("#goingtoadd").val()!="")
    document.getElementById('adding').innerHTML+='<br/><input name="checkbox65" class="checkbox65" type="checkbox" />'+$("#goingtoadd").val();
    $("#goingtoadd").val("");
})
});
```

[See this Fiddle for Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/QFhnc/)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a pure javascript based solution here is it:

```
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var table = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode,
        rowsLen = table.rows.length,
        beforeLastRow = table.rows[rowsLen - 2],
        inputToAdd = document.querySelector('#textinput4');

    var newRow = beforeLastRow.cloneNode(true),
        input = newRow.querySelector('input');

    input.checked = false;

    var label = newRow.querySelector('label');
    label.innerHTML = "";
    label.appendChild(input);
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputToAdd.value));
    inputToAdd.value = "";

    table.insertBefore(newRow, table.rows[rowsLen - 1]);
}, false);
```

Here is a jsFiddle to test it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/subhamsaha1004/2G9Qv/